# The close reason for resource recommendations could use a better description

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This is the current text for the close reason.

> ##### Brief Description
>
> Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
>
> ##### Usage guidance
>
> This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

I see several problems with it:

- "And more" is ambiguous and unneeded. There are better ways to express that the list of resources may not be complete.
- It doesn't mention that the recommendations need to be "external", "off-site", or "3rd-party."
  I've seen confusion about this.  For example, seeking recommendations about how to fix a bug shouldn't be covered by this reason because it is asking for something that be completely provided in an answer.
- It doesn't mention that external resource requests attract spam and self-promotion.  A big part of the reason for this rule is that external resource requests end up taking a lot of moderation effort in the future.  It would be nice to acknowledge this in the close reason text.

Comment: I mean agree, but we also have to keep in mind that it is a delicate balance between correctness and terseness. Make text too long, people don't read it. Make them too short, people start to fill in the blanks themselves. You did that as well in this case since in your own suggestion you say "external recommendations". I can assure you that asking for links to Stack Overflow posts is also not allowed :) My interpretation of it was that recommendations of any kind are off-topic, but that is too broad a statement as offering a solution to a problem is technically also a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The following would be a big improvement:

> ##### Brief description
>
> Asking for external recommendations
>
> ##### Usage guidance
>
> Questions asking for recommendations for external websites, tools, resources, and software are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>
> ##### Close description
>
> This question is `[closed](/help/closed-questions)` because it is asking for recommended external websites, tools, resources, and software. It is not currently accepting answers because many would likely be opinions or spam.
>
> ##### Post owner guidance
>
> You may edit your question to remove requests for external resources.  When you do so, check the box indicating that the close reason for the question has been addressed, then the question will be reevaluated for reopening.
>
> ##### Public guidance
>
> You can suggest edits to this question that remove recommendation requests or leave comments suggesting how the author might improve their question. Please respond to the author if they have any questions about the process to get the question reopened, and nominate this question for reopening if it has been edited to be on-topic.